# error LGHT0204 : ICE57: Component 'XXX' has both per-user data and a keypath that can be either per-user or per-machine

Tags: wix, windows-installer

What does error "error LGHT0204 : ICE57: Component 'XXX' has both per-user data and a keypath that can be either per-user or per-machine" mean?
Is it possible to fix this error?
In any case Wix creates the msi file and it is possible to install the application. Is it the real error or just a warning? Can I ignore this error in case if it is a warning? Or something should be corrected?
This is wxs file for my Single Package Authoring installation:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<Wix xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi'>
  <Product Name='Foobar 1.0' Id='GUID' UpgradeCode='GUID'
    Language='1033' Codepage='1252' Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'>

    <Package Id='*' Keywords='Installer' Description="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installer"
      Comments='Foobar is a registered trademark of Acme Ltd.' Manufacturer='Acme Ltd.'
      InstallerVersion='100' Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />

    <Property Id="ALLUSERS" Secure="yes" Value="2" />
    <Property Id="MSIINSTALLPERUSER" Secure="yes" Value="1" />
    <Property Id='ApplicationFolderName' Value="Acme" />
    <Property Id='WixAppFolder' Value="WixPerUserFolder" />

    <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' DiskPrompt="CD-ROM #1" />
    <Property Id='DiskPrompt' Value="Acme's Foobar 1.0 Installation [1]" />

    <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
      <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
        <Directory Id='Acme' Name='Acme'>
          <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='Foobar 1.0'>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0">
          <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="GUID">
            <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
            <RegistryValue Root='HKMU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
          </Component>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>

    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
       <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='GUID'>
          <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1' Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' >
             <Shortcut Id="startmenuFoobar10" Directory="ProgramMenuDir" Name="Foobar 1.0" WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' Icon="Foobar10.exe" IconIndex="0" />
          </File>
          <RegistryKey Root="HKMU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]">
             <RegistryValue Name="FoobarEXE" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" Type="integer" />
          </RegistryKey>
       </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id='Complete' Title='Foobar 1.0' Description='The complete package.'
      Display='expand' Level='1' ConfigurableDirectory='INSTALLDIR'>
      <Feature Id='MainProgram' Title='Program' Description='The main executable.' Level='1'>
        <ComponentRef Id='MainExecutable' />
        <ComponentRef Id='ProgramMenuDir' />
      </Feature>
    </Feature>

    <Icon Id="Foobar10.exe" SourceFile="FoobarAppl10.exe" />

  </Product>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 3):

The intention of the ICE57 checks is to verify components are not mixing per-user and per-machine files and/or registry settings.  However Rob Mensching's comment in http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/26687047/ indicates the ICE57 checks are not perfect:

> IIRC, this is a bug in ICE57. The Windows Installer team didn't look at
>   ALLUSERS property when evaluating these values... that was a long time ago
>   though so my memory may have decayed a bit.

Your sample looks correct with respect to *Single Package Authoring* rules.  The two main target directories are *ProgramFilesFolder* and *ProgramMenuFolder*, both of which are redirected appropriately for per-user installs.  The registry key root is HKMU, which ends up as HKLM on per-machine installs and HKCU on per-user installs.

This looks like a bug in ICE57.  Sadly we don't have access to the ICE57 source, so it is difficult to fix directly.  There are a couple of options to work around the problem:

**Option 1 - Suppress ICE57**

Not ideal because it suppresses all four rules this group, not just the rule that is failing.

**Option 2 - Use Advertised Shortcuts**

Change your short-cut to advertised, and lose the associated registry key.  The `MainExecutable` component simplifies to:

```
   <Component Id='MainExecutable' Guid='GUID'>
      <File Id='FoobarEXE' Name='FoobarAppl10.exe' DiskId='1'
            Source='FoobarAppl10.exe' KeyPath='yes'>
         <Shortcut Id="startmenuFoobar10" 
                   Directory="ProgramMenuDir" 
                   Name="Foobar 1.0" 
                   WorkingDirectory='INSTALLDIR' 
                   Icon="Foobar10.exe" 
                   IconIndex="0" 
                   Advertise='yes'/>
      </File>
   </Component>
```

The ICE57 checks seem to be more reliable with advertised short-cuts.

**Note about ICE Checks**

All of the ICE checks are stored in the file **darice.cub**.  This is actually a Windows Installer database file that you can open with **Orca**.  In a typical WIX installation this file can be found in: `C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset vX.Y\bin`.  If you open **darice.cub** in **Orca** you can see the ICE checks as custom actions.  Most refer to one or more binary DLLs embedded in the file.  A few are implemented as VBS.

Comment: It's not a bug. The static value of ALLUSERS in an MSI file is irrelevant because many installs flip between per user and per machine at runtime. The test it self is static, and the warning is there for per machine installs.

Comment: @PhilDW Thank you, I already read all those posts that you mentioned in your answer. But I still do not understand what is wrong with my example. If it is not a bug then my example is wrong? If my example is wrong - how to fix it?

Comment: I want to mention that I am also experiencing ICE57 error, and I've done everything pretty much as the Wix tutorial on wixtoolset.org suggests. The linker generates the MSI file but complains with ICE57. I don't think advertised shortcuts should be the solution here, as far as I understand they're a bit of an unrelated feature here.

Comment: I used `Scope="perMachine"` in `Package` and I expected to got perMache behaviour without flipping to perUser mode

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked dozens of times. Rather than post all the links, please search for ICE57 in SO and refer to the explanations and answers. For example this:

[(WiX) Program files shortcut for per-machine install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245832/wix-program-files-shortcut-for-per-machine-install)

and this:

[How to fix ICE57.Per-User installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422601/how-to-fix-ice57-per-user-installation)

Short answer: Ignore it if you always install per user and fix it if you install per system. It's a static test on the MSI file and can't know which context the install will eventually be, so it gives the warning anyway.